# passing username in websocket connection

Tags: websocket

I am trying to implement a websocket for my application. I have managed to make almost everything working as expected but I am stuck on one simple thing: **how to pass a username on connection**

My node code on connection:

```
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  const currentTime = Date.now();

  // Unique id is assigned, set username to Anonymous and set login time
  // to each client after the connection is made.
  Object.assign(ws, {id: uuid.v4(), username: 'Anonymous', date: currentTime});

  // Send the event back to client so it can display a new user is added.
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({type:'new_user', text: 'Anonymous', id: ws.id, date: currentTime}));

  // Also send a broadcast message so other users can get notified.
  broadCastThis({type:'public_msg', text: 'Someone just joined!', from: null, date: currentTime});
```

This will define "Anonymous" as username.

The client is connecting with this code:

```
function connect() {
  if (!window.location.hostname) {
    chatSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000");
  }
  else {
    chatSocket = new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws'));
  }
  chatSocket.onopen = event => {
    // On chatsocket open, loop through all the input textbox
    // and make them enabled except for private chat.
    // Private chat will be enabled whenever someone click on you and vice-versa.
    let inputNodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    if (inputNodes.length) {
      inputNodes.forEach(elInput => {
        if (elInput.getAttribute('id') !== 'private-text') {
          elInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
      });
    }
  };

  // On receive message, render these on screen.
  chatSocket.onmessage = event => {
    let msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    writeMessage(msg);
  };
}
```

How do I add the username on connection and how do i parse it on server? The username is already available on the client page coming from a php session